# Load UIView from nib file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, interface-builder

I have one large view with a toolbar that allows a user to select how they want data displayed. When they select what data they want displayed, a smaller UIView (contained within the original one) should change to show the data they want displayed.

I would like to load that small UIView from a different nib file, but the toolbar (in the larger view) should not disappear, i.e. I don't want that view larger to go away, only the small view should be changed. I have different nib files for each data view.

How can I load the small UIView from a given nib file?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I've did this before.

```
SimpleCell *cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FriendsCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

owner is not necessary. and the index should be the same of the index inside the nib. (the first object(Not the `file's owner` nor `First Response`)  starts from 0)